# How to run a setup before all test suites?

Tags: robotframework

I know that there are Setup and Suite Setup in RobotFramework, but if I want to do something before a test, and this test package refers to multiple Test Suites. How do I achieve it.

Like below how to achieve all Test Setup & all Test Teardown

```
**All Test Setup**
    Suite Setup
        Case Setup
            Case1
        Case Teardown
        Case Setup
            Case2
        Case Teardown
    Suite Teardown
    Suite Setup
        Case Setup
            Case1
        Case Teardown
        Case Setup
            Case2
        Case Teardown
    Suite Teardown
**All Test Teardown**
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787384/robot-framework-run-setup-for-an-entire-test-suite?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly than all files, [all directories are test suites](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#files-and-directories). Thus, for global setup and teardown, you will have to define a `Suite setup` and `Suite teardown` for your top level test suite: the directory which holds all your test directories. To do this, create [__init__.robot](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-initialization-files) file to this directory and define the setup and teardown there.